# Вывод не просроченных данных

Tags: база-данных

Делаю страницу вакансий и надо выводить только те, у которых срок не прошел.
В БД создал exp_time поле,тип - Date.
Выполняю выборку

```
$db = Db::getConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `".$locale."_vacancy` WHERE exp_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP";
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);

    $result->execute();
    $vacancyData = $result->fetch();
    return $vacancyData;
```

Пробовал и `WHERE exp_date > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` и `WHERE exp_date > NOW()`
Но, чую, что это не правильно. Может кто поможет

Comment: Почему вы думаете, что это не правильно ? какие то ошибки возвращаются или не те данные выбирает ? А что именно писать CURRENT_TIMESTAMP или NOW() или например еще что нибудь, зависит от используемой вами СУБД, которую в вопросе вы не указали

Comment: Без условия все хорошо выводит, а с условием нет. СУБД - вы подразумеваете СУБДОМЕН? Тогда http://DOMAIN/en. Но проблема не в этом

Comment: Что значит "нет". выполните запрос там где будет видно ошибки или добавьте такую проверку в данный код. и может у вас в таблицах нет записей у которых exp_date в будующем

Comment: Вы были правы название поля не правильно записал. Чет тупанул. Спасибо